# Check online or offline?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

What is the easiest way to trigger a function when the device becomes online or offline with **Android Webview**.I found this one.

`window.addEventListener('online',  update OnlineStatus);`

but  it is not working in android webview

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine

Comment: @Zee it works on webpage not in android webview

Comment: @Satpal it works on webpage not in android webview

Answer (score 2):

Try to access any small size file like image on your server, If it not found then it means, user is not Connected ! this way you can find online or offline

Answer (score 1):

Do whatever you want in the callback where there is the alert when connection is lost

```
document.addEventListener("offline", function(){ alert("No connection found") }, false);
```

Comment: @AshBringer question is to  trigger a function when the device becomes online or offline in  Android Webview not in browser

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333047/checking-internet-connection-in-webview

Answer (score 0):

Try to access any small size file like `image` on your server, If it not found then it means, user is *not Connected* !

**JavaScript Function:**

```
function doesConnectionExist() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var file = "img/a.png";        //path of image on your server/internet
    var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
    xhr.open('HEAD', file + "?rand=" + randomNum, false);
    try {
        xhr.send(null);
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Call above function on any event which makes server call :
if it returns `true`, then the user is connected!

Comment: it is only for check connection at a particular point.but how to trigger an event if connection goes online or offline

Comment: you have to call this function on JavaScript local events only

Comment: using timer to check this function continously is not a good idea

Comment: I don't mean to use timer! buddy, I am saying to call this function where u make server call in javascript!

Comment: i want to execute certain functions at the time when browser becomes online and also in the case of offline

Comment: it seems to be not the actual solution,Thank you for the tip

Comment: @visakhsujathan - use the setTimeout function inside the function to call the request, say every millisecond, and check the connection

Comment: @visakhsujathan, you can accept answer.. if no other works